# having C playing different frequencies on my speakers

Tags: c

In school, we are using some Lego Mindstorm robots and their respective program, RobotC to program a song of our choice. After working long and hard on it, I decided to bring it home to work on it there, the only problem is that I don't have a Lego Mindstorm at home, therefore rendering it impossible for me to listen to the finished product. So I realized that I would have to write a new program, and running it from there, so my question is, is it possible to have a program written in C play different frequencies on my speakers? and if so, could you please provide some examples, because I have no idea.

```
float fNote = 107,      // Whole Note
hNote = fNote/2,        // Half Note
qNote = hNote/2,        // Quarter Note
eNote = qNote/2,        // Eighth Note
sNote = eNote/2,        // Sixteenth Note
tNote = sNote/2,        // Thirtysecond Note
xtNote = tNote/2,       // Sixtyfourth Note

float FLow = 349,   // Note: Low F
A = 440,            // Note: A
B = 466,            // Note: B
EHigh = 659,        // Note: High E
DHigh = 587,        // Note: High D
GLow= 392,          // Note: Low G
ELow = 330,         // Note: Low E
Rest = 0,           // Note: Rest
C = 523,            // Note: C
DLow = 294,         // Note: Low D
FHigh = 698,        // Note: High F
GHigh = 783,        // Note: High G

task main()
{
//start 1
playTone(FLow,eNote);       // Frequency: 349
wait10Msec(eNote+xtNote);
playTone(A,eNote);          // Frequency: 440
wait10Msec(eNote+xtNote);
playTone(B,qNote);          // Frequency: 466
wait10Msec(qNote+xtNote);
}
```

a bit of sample code from my mindstorm program

Comment: Standard C99 or C11 does not know about speakers or sounds, so your question is platform specific (and not much C specific)

Comment: ...and since it's platform specific, it's unlikely that a solution that works for your PC at home would bear much resemblance to the solution that works for the Mindstorm robot.

Comment: ok, i do not know the difference in between C99 and C11, i just write and save as the filetype C

Comment: if you can cut and paste your RobotC code, we might be able to suggest something similar.

Comment: it doesnt matter if my solution at home doesnt work on the school computers, i have that code all sorted already

Comment: it is around 250 lines of code, most of them the same function called again and again, therefore posting the code would be a pain in the ass, unless you want me to post it on another website

Comment: just paste a few lines.

Comment: What C compiler are you using at home? Windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: windows, both at school and home

Comment: what lines would you want?

Comment: if you look at my sample code, you see what i am calling and what not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for making noise you can use `beep(frequency, duration)`,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

for silence use `Sleep(duration)`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a .NET package called NAudio that will let you synthesize tones on a PC. You'd have to write in C# or Visual Basic or C++/CLR.

Here's an introduction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309883.aspx

Comment: does it accept the frequencies in Hz or do i have to define it in some other way?

Comment: I don't know, but Jasen's answer above would be better anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit complex, but I recommend using GStreamer for this task. To play a single frequency, you can use this example code:

```
static void play_sound (gdouble frequency) {
    GstElement *source, *sink;
    GstElement *pipeline;

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("note");
    source   = gst_element_factory_make ("audiotestsrc", "source");
    sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "output");

    /* set frequency */
    g_object_set (source, "freq", frequency, NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link (source, sink);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    /* stop it after 500ms */
    g_timeout_add (LENGTH, (GSourceFunc) pipeline_stop, pipeline);
}
```

The `audiotestsrc` is a tone generator, and `autoaudiosink` is the default sound device of the system. This code is a part of a [Guitar Tuner example application](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/guitar-tuner.c.html.en). The full [source code](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/guitar-tuner/guitar-tuner.c) is here by the way.

The current version of GStreamer (for Windows) can be installed from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.4.5/). I recommend using [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) for development, as you can download it with the MinGW compiler pre-bundled, which is AFAIK necessary for GLib and GStreamer.